# Where to place the resources of her application so that they are installed on the SD card?

Tags: android, sd-card, android-2.2-froyo

I have big files to integrate into my application (videos), and thus for not not that my application occupies all the internal memory of the telephones, I saw that it was possible with Froyo to install the applications on the SD card.

I thus have to test this solution and my application settles down well on the SD card, the only problem it is that the system installs all the same my files videos (which are placed in the file /raw) on the internal memory of the telephone. Thus my question it is where to place my videos or where to make so that these also settle down on the SD carde?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I add preferExeternal in my AndroidManifest ...
When I install my application with ApkInstaller, the application is installed on the SD Card, but with the Android Market, the application settles down on the telephone...

I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. Have you enabled installation on SD card in your manifest? 
You need to add

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

parameter to your AndroidManifest.xml to force app to be installed on card. For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.stackoverflow"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

Comment: Yes I add preferExeternal in my AndroidManifest ... When I install my application with ApkInstaller, the application is installed on the SD Card, but with the Android Market, the application settles down on the telephone...

I don't understand why...

Comment: The feature only supported by 2.2 platform now. Does your device with market have the Android 2.2 installed? Also I it can depend on device, probably vendor has added a preference to allow user to force install location.

Answer (score 0):

Does it give you the option to move it to the SD card? (from the application manager in the settings)

Is this an update for a previous app?(because it can take a while for updates to roll out)